# jQuery - адаптивный и динамичный текст

Tags: html, jquery, css

Есть блок `.text-wrap` с заданным размером, есть массив из текстовых строк в jQuery (разной длины и дополняющийся). Задача - при нажатии кнопки вписать рандомный текст в блок подогнав размер его шрифта. С рандомным текстом вопросов нет, вопросы именно в адаптивности =)

Первое что пришло в голову:

В `.text-wrap` добавить еще один `div` с авто высотой и шириной 100%;
получается так

```
<div class=".text-wrap">
  <div class = ".text"> Тут текстовая строка  </div>
</div>
```

В внутренний блок добавляем текст с заведомо огромным размером шрифта и далее уменьшаем шрифт, пока высота внутреннего не станет меньше внешнего блока.

Делал через `while`, функция работает. Но на некоторые тексты она делает по 300-400 проходов. Особенно если шаг уменьшения шрифта маленький. тогда решил сократить через рекурсию и множитель. Получается примерно 13-15 шагов на двустрочный текст.

Вот код:

```
jQuery.noise = 15; //погрешность ресайза в пикс
    jQuery.step = 100; //шаг
    jQuery.startFontSize = 200; //стартовый размер шрифта
    jQuery.currentFontSize = 100; //текущий размер шрифта 
    jQuery.stepCounter = 0; //счетчик действий
    jQuery.stepper = 1; //множитель шага шрифта (на это чилсо делим)     
function changeSizeDown(he1, block) //he1 - высота внешнего блока, block - блок с текстом
    {
           //если мы добились своего, заканчиваем рекурсию
          if(he1 - jQuery.noise < block.height()  &&   block.height() < he1 + jQuery.noise) { //noise - погрешность высоты (т.к. 100% малый шанс попасть)
            return 1; 
        }
        //иначе, если высота текста больше высоты блока
        else if(block.height() > he1) {
            jQuery.currentFontSize -= Math.ceil(jQuery.step/jQuery.stepper); 
            console.log('Step: '+jQuery.stepCounter+' / Side: down / fsize: ' + jQuery.currentFontSize + ' / mult: x'+jQuery.stepper); 
            console.log('Blocks: '+block.height()+' / ' + he1); 

            block.css("font-size", jQuery.currentFontSize + "px"); 
            changeSizeDown(he1, block);
        }
        //если высота блока меньше, то увеличиваем шрифт
         else if(block.height() < he1) {
            if(jQuery.stepper < 50) //если множитель шага < 50, то умножаем вдвое
                jQuery.stepper = jQuery.stepper*2;
            else //иначе мы уже подобрали максимально близкий размер шрифта, а шагов сделали слишком много. Поэтому стоп.
                return 0;
            jQuery.currentFontSize += Math.ceil(jQuery.step/jQuery.stepper); 

            console.log('Step: '+jQuery.stepCounter+' / Side: up / fsize: ' + jQuery.currentFontSize + ' / mult: x'+jQuery.stepper); 
            console.log('Blocks: '+block.height()+' / ' + he1);             
            block.css("font-size", jQuery.currentFontSize + "px"); 
            changeSizeDown(he1, block);
        }
    }
```

Данный код быстро справляется со своей задачей. Но, как и цикл, на мобильных устройствах иногда работает некорректно. А именно через раз меняет размер, через раз не меняет.

Может у кого есть идеи или более простые решения? Гуглил очень много. Сразу скажу что всякие `fitText` мне не подходят, т.к. они только от ширины отталкиваются. А у меня задана и ширина и высота.

Answer (score 1):

Итак, если кому интересно. Разобрался с большинством своих ошибок.

```
jQuery.noise = 15; //погрешность ресайза в пикс
jQuery.step = 100; //шаг размера шрифта в пикс
jQuery.startFontSize = 200; //стартовый размер шрифта
jQuery.currentFontSize = 200; //текущий размер шрифта 
jQuery.stepper = 1; //множитель
jQuery.stopper = false; //стоппер

function changeSize(he1, block) {  //he1 - необходимая высота //block - div с текстом
//если мы находимся в пределах допустимой погрешности, то все ок, завершаем работу или если поступила команда стопера
if(he1 - jQuery.noise < block.height()  &&   block.height() < he1 + jQuery.noise || jQuery.stopper == true) {
    block.css('line-height', jQuery.currentFontSize + (jQuery.currentFontSize/10) + 'px'); //высота строки (настройте под себя)
    var padding = (he1 - block.height())/2 + "px"; // т.к. у нас есть погрешность, остатки я выравниваю за счет отступов
    block.css('padding-top', padding);
    block.css('padding-bottom', padding);
    //тут и была моя первая ошибка. Я не обнулял счетчики =))
    jQuery.stopper = false;
    jQuery.stepCounter = 0;
    jQuery.stepper = 1;
    return 1; 
}

//если высота блока больше чем необходимая, уменьшаем
else if(block.height() > he1) {
    //уменьшаем размер шрифта на шаг / множитель
    jQuery.currentFontSize -= Math.ceil(jQuery.step/jQuery.stepper); 
    block.css("font-size", jQuery.currentFontSize + "px"); 
    return changeSizeDown(he1, block); //рекурсия
}
//если высота блока меньше чем необходимая, увеличиваем (и увеличиваем вдвое stepper)
else if(block.height() < he1) {
    //тут ограничитель множителя. Методом проб и ошибок выяснилось, что для моих нужд множитель более 50 - излишне. Когда множитель больше 50 мы уже очень близки к нужному размеру, потому тормозим скрипт. Иначе умножаем вдвое
    if(jQuery.stepper < 50)
        jQuery.stepper = jQuery.stepper*2;
    else{
        jQuery.stopper = true;
        return changeSizeDown(he1, block);
    }    
    jQuery.currentFontSize += Math.ceil(jQuery.step/jQuery.stepper);           
    block.css("font-size", jQuery.currentFontSize + "px"); 

    return changeSizeDown(he1, block); //рекурсия
} }
```

Перед вызовом скрипта необходимо:

1. присвоить стартовый размер шрифта блоку.
2. Высоту строки сделать нормальной. `line-height:normal`
3. убрать `padding`

Мой пример вызова:

```js
//при загрузке страницы
$(window).load(function() {
  updateAdvice();
});

//при ресайзе страницы. Выполняем только, когда ресайз закончил. За это отвечает функция debouncer
function debouncer(func, timeout) {
  var timeoutID, timeout = timeout || 200;
  return function() {
    var scope = this,
      args = arguments;
    clearTimeout(timeoutID);
    timeoutID = setTimeout(function() {
      func.apply(scope, Array.prototype.slice.call(args));
    }, timeout);
  }
}

$(window).resize(debouncer(function(e) {
  adapt();
}));


//Переменные
jQuery.noise = 15; //погрешность ресайза в пикс
jQuery.step = 100; //шаг
jQuery.startFontSize = 200; //стартовый размер шрифта
jQuery.currentFontSize = 200; //текущий размер шрифта 
jQuery.stepper = 1; //множитель
jQuery.lastAd = 0;
jQuery.stopper = false;

//ТЕКСТ (для примера взят с http://fucking-great-advice.ru/ )
jQuery.adv = ['Не опускай руки!', 'Не делай плохого!', 'Упал — отряхнись!', 'Соблюдай режим!', 'Группируй задачи!', 'Не срывай сроки!', 'Мысли масштабнее!', 'Учись готовить!', 'Признавай свои ошибки!'];


//Замена текста
function updateAdvice() {
  $('.text').text(jQuery.adv[rand(jQuery.adv.length)]);
  adapt();
}


//ФУНКЦИЯ РАНДОМНОГО ЧИСЛА//
function rand(max) {
  var rand = jQuery.lastAd;
  while (rand == jQuery.lastAd) {
    rand = Math.random() * (max - 1);
    rand = Math.round(rand);
  }
  jQuery.lastAd = rand;
  return rand;
}


//АДАПТАЦИЯ
function adapt() {
  //Обнуляем все
  $('.text').css('opacity', '0');
  $('.text').css('padding-top', '0px');
  $('.text').css('padding-bottom', '0px');
  $('.text').css("font-size", jQuery.startFontSize + "px");
  $('.text').css('line-height', 'normal');
  jQuery.currentFontSize = jQuery.startFontSize;
  //стартуем
  changeSizeDown($('.text-wrap').height(), $('.text'))
}




function changeSizeDown(he1, block) {
  jQuery.stepCounter++; //счетчик действий
  if (jQuery.stepCounter > 50) {
    updateAdvice();
    return 0;
  };
  //если мы находимся в пределах допустимой погрешности, то все ок, завершаем работу
  if (he1 - jQuery.noise < block.height() && block.height() < he1 + jQuery.noise || jQuery.stopper == true) {
    block.css('line-height', jQuery.currentFontSize + (jQuery.currentFontSize / 10) + 'px');
    var padding = (he1 - block.height()) / 2 + "px";
    block.css('padding-top', padding);
    block.css('padding-bottom', padding);
    block.animate({
      opacity: 1,
    }, 300);
    jQuery.stopper = false;
    jQuery.stepCounter = 0;
    jQuery.stepper = 1;
    return 1;
  }
  //если высота блока больше чем необходимая, уменьшаем
  else if (block.height() > he1) {
    jQuery.currentFontSize -= Math.ceil(jQuery.step / jQuery.stepper);
    block.css("font-size", jQuery.currentFontSize + "px");
    return changeSizeDown(he1, block);
  }
  //если высота блока меньше чем необходимая, увеличиваем (и увеличиваем вдвое stepper)
  else if (block.height() < he1) {
    if (jQuery.stepper < 50)
      jQuery.stepper = jQuery.stepper * 2;
    else {
      jQuery.stopper = true;
      return changeSizeDown(he1, block);
    }
    jQuery.currentFontSize += Math.ceil(jQuery.step / jQuery.stepper);

    block.css("font-size", jQuery.currentFontSize + "px");

    return changeSizeDown(he1, block);
  }
}

//КНОПКА//
$('.button').on('click', function() {
  updateAdvice();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='text-wrap' style="width: 400px; height: 300px; background-color: #d8d8d8;">
  <div class='text'>
    sdfsdfef
  </div>
</div>
<div class='button'>Поменять</div>
```

Comment: слово "масштабнее" не влезает

Comment: да, есть еще много, что нужно доработать) В данном случае проверку по ширине